# Can I change the way a $.fn. function is declared?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.fn.buildTableOfContent = function () {
    var h2 = this.find('h2');
    if (h2.length > 0) {
```

I would like to change it around so it's not declared as a variable:

```
function $.fn.buildTableOfContent () {
    var h2 = this.find('h2');
    if (h2.length > 0) {
```

Is it possible to do this like the above? I have done this for regular functions but not sure about ones that start with $.fn.  Am I correct in saying that $.fn. adds the function the the jQuery namespace?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There might be a better way, if we know what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well I have been converting all of my var a = function () { } to function a() {}.  I didn't convert this one yet as I was not sure if it was different from normal functions.

Comment: This does not make it any clearer as to _why_ you're doing that in the first place.

Comment: @lanzz - I just wanted all the function declarations to look the same. However if this is not possible I am quite okay with the way it is. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to do that.

From the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x13):

> FunctionDeclaration :
>       function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) {
>   FunctionBody }
>
> FunctionExpression :
>      function Identifier<sub>opt</sub> ( FormalParameterListopt )
>   { FunctionBody }

`$.fn.buildTableOfContent` is an expression, not an identifier, thus it is invalid syntax.